# Include image by pointing to alias

Tags: graphics, mactex

For my document I have an image folder that holds my images. For this example I will assume the following situation:

Original image path: `~/Matlab/filename.pdf`
Image folder path: `~/Latex/images`
Alias to image: `~/Latex/images/filename.pdf`

I want to include the image by pointing to the alias of the image. In this way the image will be updated when Matlab updates `filename.pdf` in the `~/Matlab` folder.
I've tried it as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[!htpb] 
\centering 
\includegraphics[clip=true, trim=0 170 0 170, width=0.33\linewidth, angle=0]{images/filename.pdf} 
\caption{CAPTION} 
\label{fig:} 
\end{figure}
```

However, TexShop (I'm on a Mac) does not like this and produces the following error:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ./images/mountdiff.pdf): xpdf: reading PDF image failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I link to the file in the Matlab folder, without typing the whole path in the `\includegraphics` line. Typing the whole path is undesirable as it is much longer than the example suggests.

Comment: What do you mean with "alias to image"? It should be a symbol link (shell command line: `ln -s ~/Matlab/filename.pdf ~/Latex/images/filename.pdf`).

Comment: Thank you @HeikoOberdiek Shortly after posting this question I found this out. But with alias I mean the file you get when you rightclick on a file and press `Make Alias`. Or when you hold opt+cmd during dragging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shortly after posting this question I found out that a symbolic link is not the same as an alias and tried using a symbolic link.
I've made a symbolic link in `~/Latex/images` to the file in `~/Matlab` by using [SymbolicLinker](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10433/symboliclinker) (I'm not affiliated in any way). A symbolic link can also be made in Terminal as follows (file/folder names as given in the example):

```
cd ~/Latex/images  
ln -s ~/Matlab/filename.pdf filename.pdf
```

Then `images/filename.pdf` can be used regularly in `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Yes; only applications using the user interfaces provided by Mac OS X can profit of Finder aliases. TeX Live programs know only about symbolic links, and Finder aliases are a very different thing.