# How to include symlinked graphics with spaces?

Tags: graphics, external-files, mactex, paths

I symlink to images and reference the symlink in the code. This works well as long the filename ends in an extension. However, [the method I use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106250/13134) to create symlinks creates symlinked files with the following filename:

```
filename.pdf symlink
```

If I use that filename in `\includegraphics`, in combination with this answer to handle the space, I get the following error:

```
Unknown graphics extension: .pdf symlink
```

Is there a way to solve this error, except for renaming the symlinked files?

Comment: Does it have a special reason that you append the "symlink" to your files?

Comment: I have some doubts that you really want a file name `filename.pdf symlink` with extension `.pdf symlink`. If you creating the symbolic link on the command line and the files might contain spaces, then quoting helps: `ln -s "file name.pdf" "new file name.pdf"`.

Comment: @BenediktBauer I use [Symlinker](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41493/symlinker) to create the symlinks. That program appends symlink to the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define a rule for this new extension. You can also avoid adding the extension with the help of the `grfext

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grfext}

\PrependGraphicsExtensions*{.pdf symlink}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.pdf symlink}{pdf}{*}{}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example-image.pdf symlink}

\includegraphics{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Both lines will work. However, spaces in file names are often a nuisance. A scheme such as

```
example-image.pdf-symlink
```

seems a better choice.

Comment: Out of curiosity to learn: Is `space` character in file or figure names good practice to have it in symlink on all platforms ?

Comment: @texenthusiast I would never use spaces in file names. My test on Mac OS X works; I can't guarantee on other systems.